# How to output a string in java so that the words dont get split up?

Tags: java, formatting, space

I started learning java and basically wanted to do some coding for practice. My search landed me to javaranch and i did their first assignment which was not that hard. The hard part for me was the second part. The first part is that you just simply write a program that will read in a name from the command line and write it out 100 times. Now the second part wants me to display the word in such a way that it doesn't get split up at the edge of the screen. As soon as the word doesn't fit at the right side it wants me to move the whole word to the next line. Here is my code.

```
    public class Hundred
{
    public static void main( String [] args)
    {
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i <=100; i++)
        {
            if  (args.length == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("I've got nothing to show you");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print( args[0] + " ");
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Place the `for` statement inside the `else` part. Then somehow maintain the line length printed till it would supersede 80 and do println i.o. print(" ").

Comment: do you mean the edge of a command prompt console window or your IDE's? because command prompt does have a character limit per line which you can check and add a newline to your string if it is over the amount and the word would get split up

Answer (score 1):

Separate the view from the model: create the thing you want to print before you print it.

Like this:

```
import java.io.StringWriter;

public class Hundred {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(1024);
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
            sw.append(args[i]).append(' ');
        }
        System.out.println(sw.toString());
    }
}
```

Add logic inside the loop to check the length of the current StringWriter and print and flush if it exceeds your requirements.